# Notepad++ Regex Second match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following file structure

```
_____00000
_____00600
_____00004
_____00036
```

*the line is equivalent to whitespaces

and i want to transform in this

```
'00000
'00600
'00004
'00036
```

In the replace tab i am using in the "Find what" ^\sd
And in the Replace with '{0}

but the result is not the expected

```
'______000000
'______006000
```

.......

and if i use '{1}

So

```
'00000
'06000
```

It takes out one digit ...

How can i achieve my goal ?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Comment: Are those simple underscores, or what do they represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as pattern `^\s+` to search all spaces at the begining of a line and as replacement `'`

(Sorry for my french Notepad++, but I bet you can easily understand)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your example data you could use `^\h+` to match one or more horizontal whitespace characters without the `\d` because that will match a digit and replace with a single quote.

**Find what**

[`^\h+`](https://regex101.com/r/1PbbKI/1)

**Replace with**

'

If there should be digits following the whitespace you might use a positive lookahead. If the digits also need to be at the end of the line you could add `$` to assert the end of the line `(?=\d+$)`

[`^\h+(?=\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/T07Ven/1)

Comment: OP asked for single quote as replacement

Comment: I missed that one. Updated

Comment: Maybe he needs to remove leading spaces of lines that begin with digits?

Comment: @revo You are right, that could also be possible. I have added an update.

Answer (score 1):

Search for below regex:

```
^\s+(\d+)$
```

and replace it with

```
'\1
```

And also ensure that `Regular Expressions` is checked in `Search Mode`

I have checked this and is working fine.

Comment: This is the most precise answer so far. However, note that `\s` matches line breaks, too, so `\h` can be a better fit here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`^\s+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/cqpgzZ/1)

And replace with `'$1`

- `^` makes sure you're at the beginning of a line
- `s+` matches an ywhitespace character
- `(.*)` matches anything after that

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/cqpgzZ/1)

[image: Notepad Demo]